# How to set height of wrapper to contain carousal images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to set the width of a carousal to 90% and adapt height automatically.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
  var currentSlide = 0;

  function showSlide(index) {
    if (index >= slides.length) {
      currentSlide = 0;
    } else if (index < 0) {
      currentSlide = slides.length - 1;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].classList.remove('active');
    }

    slides[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
  }

  function nextSlide() {
    currentSlide++;
    showSlide(currentSlide);
  }

  function prevSlide() {
    currentSlide--;
    showSlide(currentSlide);
  }

  setInterval(nextSlide, 4000); // Change slide every 4 seconds

  showSlide(currentSlide);
})
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 496px;
  margin: auto;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_01.jpg" alt="Image 1">
  <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_02.jpg" alt="Image 2">
  <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_03.jpg" alt="Image 3">
  <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_04.jpg" alt="Image 4">
  <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_05.jpg" alt="Image 5">
  <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_06.jpg" alt="Image 6">
</div>
```

Nothing is displayed when I set the width to 90% and height to auto. If I set height / min-height the block displays but images does not resize vertically.

Comment: *"adapt height automatically"* to what value exactly?  PS... it's *carousel*, not *carousal*.

Comment: Why do you use `width: 1200px;` if you want it to be responsive?

Answer (score 1):

working

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
var currentSlide = 0;

    function showSlide(index) {
        if (index >= slides.length) {
            currentSlide = 0;
        } else if (index < 0) {
            currentSlide = slides.length - 1;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].classList.remove('active');
        }

        slides[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
    }

    function nextSlide() {
        currentSlide++;
        showSlide(currentSlide);
    }

    function prevSlide() {
        currentSlide--;
        showSlide(currentSlide);
    }

setInterval(nextSlide, 4000); // Change slide every 4 seconds

showSlide(currentSlide);
        })
```

```css
.carousel   {
    position: relative; display:block; width: 90%; height:auto; margin:auto;
}
.slide      {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: auto; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
.slide.active   {   opacity: 1;     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
    <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_01.jpg" alt="Image 1">
    <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_02.jpg" alt="Image 2">
    <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_03.jpg" alt="Image 3">
    <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_04.jpg" alt="Image 4">
    <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_05.jpg" alt="Image 5">
    <img class='slide' src="http://www.straitshomeandgarden.com/assets/si_06.jpg" alt="Image 6">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working! Wondering what I was doing wrong?

Comment: *"working"* is not an answer in the expected quality format for this site.